# Integrate Cortana Voice Commands in Web App Without Windows Dependency

Tags: web, voice-recognition, cortana

Is it possible to use the Cortana Voice Commands functionality in a generic javascript based web application able to run in any webbrowser/platform? (e.g. through a html5 voice input and webservice of some kind) or does the webpage have to be loaded on a windows based computer with Cortana client installed?

I came across this example but it appears to expect Cortana installed on the device running the page:
https://gist.github.com/seksenov/17032e9a6eb9c17f88b5

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example you can edit the code to run for your application:
https://gist.github.com/seksenov/17032e9a6eb9c17f88b5

cortana.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cortana Example</title>
    <!--Cortana meta tag pointing to VCD file on the server-->
    <meta name="msapplication-cortanavcd" content="/vcd.xml"/>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

cortana.js

```
if (typeof Windows !== 'undefined' &&
    typeof Windows.UI !== 'undefined' &&
    typeof Windows.ApplicationModel !== 'undefined') 
  {
  // Subscribe to the Windows Activation Event
  Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("activated", function (args) {
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
    // Check to see if the app was activated by a voice command
    if (args.kind === activation.ActivationKind.voiceCommand) {
      // Get the speech reco
      var speechRecognitionResult = args.result;
      var textSpoken = speechRecognitionResult.text;
      // Determine the command type {search} defined in vcd
      if (speechRecognitionResult.rulePath[0] === "search") {
        // Determine the stream name specified
        if (textSpoken.includes('foo') || textSpoken.includes('Foo')) {
          console.log("The user is searching for foo");
        }
        else if (textSpoken.includes('bar') || textSpoken.includes('Bar') ) {
          console.log("The user is searching for a bar");
        }
        else {
          console.log("Invalid search term specified by user");
        }
      }
      else { 
        console.log("No valid command specified");
      }
    }
  });
} else {
  console.log("Windows namespace is unavaiable");
}
```

vcd.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.2">
  <CommandSet xml:lang="en-us" Name="RJS">
    <CommandPrefix>MyApp</CommandPrefix>
    <Example>MyApp search for foo</Example>
    <Command Name="Search">
      <Example>search {message} using myapp</Example>
      <ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforeOrAfterPhrase">Search for {searchTerm}</ListenFor>
      <Feedback>Searching for {searchTerm} with MyApp</Feedback>
      <Navigate Target="/search.htm"/>
    </Command>
    <PhraseTopic Label="searchTerm" Scenario="Dictation"></PhraseTopic>
  </CommandSet>
</VoiceCommands>
```

Comment: please add some content from the link.

Comment: @Robert why do you want me to add the content of the link?!

Comment: For example, if the link breaks in the future, your answer as it stands would be useless. If you add the relevant content from the link to your answer, it prevents this.